# How the evaluate operation works in ecmascript?

Tags: javascript, ecma262

i've been wondering how the `Evaluate` operation works in ecmascript.

so i've been learning about context-free grammer but i couldn't understand the exact steps when we evaluate a non-terminal symbol on the spec.

take a look at the following code

```html
var myVar = 10
```

let's assume only a `Statement` can be written there.

so my question here is what are the exact steps when we `Evaluate Statement` in this scenario ?

when we Evaluating the Statement will it go directly to the `VariableDeclaration → BindingPattern  Initializer` production runtime semantics ?

or will it go first to the runtime semantics of this `Statement → VariableStatement` chain production.

and the implicit runtime semantics for `Statement → VariableStatement` is `Return the result of evaluating VariableStatement`

so now when we `evaluate VariableStatement` it will go to this production's runtime semantics

`VariableStatement → var VariableDeclarationList;`

and this production runtime semantics will do `evaluate VariableDeclarationList`

> 1. Let next be the result of evaluating VariableDeclarationList.
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(next).
> 3. Return NormalCompletion(empty).

and now when we evaluate `VariableDeclarationList` it will go to the implicit runtime semantics of this chain production `VariableDeclarationList → VariableDeclaration`
so it will basically do this `Return the result of evaluating VariableDeclaration`

and finally `evaluating VariableDeclaration` will bring us in this scenario to this production

`VariableDeclaration → BindingIdentifier Initializer` runtime semantics

so again my question is when we evaluate the `Statement` will it go directly to the runtime semantics of `VariableDeclaration → BindingIdentifier Initializer`or will it go through those steps i've just showed you

Comment: If you do `Evaluate(statement)`, how would that know to do `Evaluate(variableDeclaration)` "instead", *without* going through the steps you mentioned?

Comment: Not sure how this isn't already answered by [your previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69511751/1048572) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69596172/1048572), can you elaborate?

Comment: **"how would that know to do Evaluate(variableDeclaration) "instead", without going through the steps you mentioned"** and that's what i find extremely confusing because VariableDeclaration is a Statement so when we Evaluate a Statement that is a VariableDeclaration isn't going to go directly to the evaluation of the VariableDeclaration ?

Comment: @Bergi do you have any logical explanation to that ? i will be honest with you this is by far the hardest thing i've ever encountered... because i use a lot of assumption and it's really driving me nuts that i can't be sure if that's exactly what the spec writers meant, i understand context free grammer quite well but there is no "evaluation operation" there

Comment: [But there is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69597409/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi in [context free grammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) there is no mention of "evaluation" operation hence i cannot read the mind of the ecmascript writers, what i know is that nonterminal symbols are used during the derivation process until we get to the terminal we wanted. i assume that when we have something like `Evaluate(Statement)` it will go to the evaluation of one of the `Statement` productions that were used during the derivation process although i haven't found any crystal clear explanations about "evaluation" in the spec that verifies it.

Comment: Evaluation does not happen during derivation. It is applied on the parse tree. Have you read [the spec section on syntax-directed operations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-algorithm-conventions-syntax-directed-operations)?

Comment: @Bergi Yes i have but it's quite hard to understand the spec considering the fact that English isn't my first language....   Sure i didn't mean that Evaluation operation happen during derivation because it doesn't make much of a sense, what you're saying is that the result of the derivation(the parse tree) is what the evaluation operation is applying to ? so basically it means that when we have evaluate `Statement` it will go to the runtime semantics of the production that was used to replace `Statement` in the parse tree which in our case is `Statement → VariableStatement` ?

Comment: @Bergi "When an algorithm is associated with a grammar production, it may reference the terminal and nonterminal symbols of the production alternative as if they were parameters of the algorithm. When used in this manner, nonterminal symbols refer to the actual alternative definition that is matched when parsing the source text" is that what you're talking about ?

Comment: @Bergi please answer me just tell me yes or no, when we evaluate a nonterminal does it referring to the runtime semantics of the production that was used to replace the nonterminal ? where in our case it's `Statement → VariableStatement`

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. "Replacing the nonterminal" created a parse node, and doing evaluation on that will use the runtime semantics for that production.